# Mule issue mapping payload dataweave 2.0

Tags: arrays, json, object, mule, dataweave

I am trying to map the below json payload to only show dates with "999" value. Below is my payload

```
 {
  "Delivery Date": "16",
  "17/01/2018": "0",
  "18/01/2018": "999",
  "19/01/2018": "999",
  "20/01/2018": "0",
  "29/01/2018": "999",
  "18/02/2018": "0",
  "19/02/2018": "999",
  "20/02/2018": "999",
  "03/03/2018": "999"
 }
```

And my desired output is

```
{ 
  "available_date": [ 
    "18/01/2018", 
    "19/01/2018, 
    "29/01/2018", 
    "19/02/2018", 
    "20/02/2018", 
    "03/03/2018"
  ],
  "message": "" 
}
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: The input is an array?

Comment: You modified the input with array now all the answers will fail because all the answers focus on the Object and not Array @aled

Comment: I didn't modify it only fixed the format to make the opening bracket visible. There was a lone closing bracket visible at the bottom. I removed both now.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative using `filterObject` and `keysOf`:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    'available_date' : keysOf(payload filterObject ((value, key, index) -> value contains "999")),
    message: ""
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this.

Approach 1 [MapObject](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-mapobject), [Pluck](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-pluck)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
"available_date":
    (payload mapObject ((value, key, index) -> ((key): (value)) if (value == "999")) pluck $$),
"message":""
}
```

Approach 2
[FilterObject](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-filterobject), [keysOf](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-keysof)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
"available_date": keysOf(payload filterObject ((value, key) -> value == "999")),
"message":""
}
```

Output

```
{
  "available_date": [
    "18/01/2018",
    "19/01/2018",
    "29/01/2018",
    "19/02/2018",
    "20/02/2018",
    "03/03/2018"
  ],
  "message": ""
}
```

Comment: Karthik and @afelisatti thank you so much both solutions work great!

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions are good. Just for completeness I'll contribute one using filterObject() then pluck().

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    available_date: payload 
                        filterObject ($ == "999")
                        pluck ((value, key, index) -> key),
    message: ""
}
```